# store image in AWS s3 bucket and then the resulted URL in database, API using postman and swagger are working fine, but test case I'm unable to write

Tags: php, rest, unit-testing

This is the controller validator.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
            'description' => 'required|string|min:5|max:1000',
            'author' => 'required|string|min:5|max:50',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,tiff|max:2048',
            'price' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer'
        ]);
```

This is my test case.

```
$response = $this->withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'Application/json',
    ])
        ->json('POST', '/api/addbook', [
            "name" => "Harry Potter Book",
            "description" => "A Series of Harry Potter Books has been Released.",
            "author" => "J.K. Rowling",
            "image" => "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince.jpg",
            "price" => "699.99",
            "quantity" => "1500",
            "token" => self::$token
        ]);
    $response->assertStatus(201)->assertJson(['message' => 'Book Added Successfully']);
```

Here in the image field, I am unable to add image. any idea how to add images in test cases, from anywhere, like storage, public, or from your system files. in to my laravel project.